# Build f2c for ARMv6, ARMv7 and i386 architecture

Tags: iphone, fortran, cross-compiling, armv7, armv6

I want to build f2c library for ARMv6, ARMv7 and i386 architectures.

I found this link ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/packages/pkgsrc/devel/libf2c/README.html, but when I used ARM libraries, Xcode generates a warning that:

> "ignoring file /Projects/Demo/FortranDemo/libf2c.a, file was built for
>   archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)"and same
>   for armv7.

Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

f2c is pretty ancient and no longer maintained, AFAIK. You might have better luck setting up gfortran. Doing it as a cross-compiler would definitely be more convenient if you can get that to work.

I don't know about iphone, but people have reported success with gfortran on android, see answers to [How to build or where to get an Android NDK stand-alone toolchain supporting fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831227/how-to-build-or-where-to-get-an-android-ndk-stand-alone-toolchain-supporting-for)