# Linking failing for PCRE when using Android NDK stand-alone toolchain

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk

People have been able to build PCRE (or a subset of) by copying the source files and creating appropriate Andriod.mk.  I want to do similar, but using an Android stand-alone toolchain and just using their configure and make process.  I have had success building other useful libraries using the same flow, but am running into an issue with PCRE.  Specifically, late in the make flow I am getting this error:

```
undefined reference to__dso_handle' .libs/pcre_stringpiece.o
```

When doing this,

```
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link arm-linux-androideabi-g++  -O2 -version-info 0:0:0                             -o libpcrecpp.la -rpath /usr/local/lib pcrecpp.lo pcre_scanner.lo pcre_stringpiece.lo libpcre.la 
libtool: link: arm-linux-androideabi-g++  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib   .libs/pcrecpp.o .libs/pcre_scanner.o .libs/pcre_stringpiece.o   -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/corbin/applications/pcre-8.21/.libs ./.libs/libpcre.so -L/home/corbin/my-android-toolchain-mod/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.0 -L/home/corbin/my-android-toolchain-mod/bin/../lib/gcc -L/home/corbin/my-android-toolchain-mod/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.0/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib -L/home/corbin/my-android-toolchain-mod/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib -lstdc++ -lm -lc -ldl -lgcc   -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libpcrecpp.so.0 -o .libs/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
.libs/pcrecpp.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_pcrecpp.cc':
pcrecpp.cc:(.text.startup+0x94): undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
.libs/pcre_stringpiece.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_pcre_stringpiece.cc':
pcre_stringpiece.cc:(.text.startup+0x40): undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libpcrecpp.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/corbin/applications/pcre-8.21'
```

Any thoughts on what the problem is and what the solution is?  I read various things about similar problems, but they were mostly unhelpful or it wasn't clear if they related to the same problem.

Update 1: I have found that this problem does not occur when I use the default stand-alone toolchain.  It only happens when I use a modified one as described here: http://specificimpulses.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-fortran-step-by-step-part-2.html
I need to use that one for building other libraries which include fortran (and have successfully done so) and want to use the same toolchain for all builds.  So, do I need to rebuild the toolchain with some different options?

Comment: Please give me a hint on how to solve this.  Or, better, make a standalone toolchain based on the link I gave and use it to build pcre.  Recreate the error and figure out what to do to fix the problem.  I believe I need to rebuild gcc with different options to get by this, but not sure how yet.

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831227/how-to-build-or-where-to-get-an-android-ndk-stand-alone-toolchain-supporting-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `-fno-use-cxa-atexit` is an acceptable workaround.